# Align div to right while expanding container

Tags: html, css

The following mark-up expands the container div (which has a background image I'd like shown), but aligns the box on the left:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container{
  background-image:url('image.png');
  width:100%;
}
.box{
  width:100px;
  height:100px
}
```

If I use `float:right` or `position:absolute;right:0px;` on the box, it aligns to the right, but the container div doesn't expand to fit the box.

Is there a way to align the box to the right side of the screen, while having the container expand to fit? Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`float:right`; on the box will work, just add `overflow:auto` on the container too.

Example below with border added to box for visibility:

```css
.container {
    background-image:url('http://www.placehold.it/100x100');
    width:100%;
    overflow:auto;
}
.box {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid red;
    float:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Also, I think OP wanted to stretch the image as the container width so set 100% on image too.

Comment: This did the trick. Thanks! Is this pretty universally supported by modern browsers?

Answer (score 0):

When using floats, you need to use a clearfix for the container:

```
.container:after {
   content: "";
   display: table;
   clear: both;
}
```

and float the box right as you were :)

This is to force the container to recognise the floated content.
A clearfix is a way for an element to automatically clear its child elements, so that you don't need to add additional markup. It's generally used in float layouts.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/v3r3p5cs/

This method will help support browsers IE 8 and up and all modern browsers

If you need less that IE8 support, as the older browsers do not support empty content, you can use:

```
.clearfix:after {
   content: " ";
   visibility: hidden;
   display: block;
   height: 0;
   clear: both;
}
```